# dbDelta wordpress cant use DECIMAL data type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

For some reason, im guessing because of the comma in DECIMAL(1,2) data type it does not work. This is what I am doing and all the dbData "rules" are being followed.

```
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    lat DECIMAL (2,9) NOT NULL,
    lng DECIMAL (2,9) NOT NULL,
    start_year INT (4) NOT NULL,
    end_year INT (4) NULL,
    articles VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    status VARCHAR (25) NULL,
    activity VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    thirdparty_link VARCHAR (125) NULL,
    address VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    );";


    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
```

If I remove this from the query above, it works without any issues.

```
lat DECIMAL (2,9) NOT NULL,
lng DECIMAL (2,9) NOT NULL,
```

How can I escape the comma in DECIMAL to make it work, or what else can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong.

This is actually not valid sql for DECIMAL data type

```
lat DECIMAL (2,9) NOT NULL,
lng DECIMAL (2,9) NOT NULL,
```

Changed to

```
lat DECIMAL (10,8) NOT NULL,
lng DECIMAL (10,8) NOT NULL,
```

And now it works :D